# How did Firefox on the Linux side of my computer know my Facebook name had changed?

Tags: facebook, firefox

I have Windows 7 and Mint Linux on my computer. I had changed the e-mail address I use to log into Facebook (and I did this on Windows). The next time I logged into Linux it had the updated e-mail address in the username field, as if it had previously been cached. Does Facebook use Ajax or something to automatically update the old e-mail address to the new one? Or does the Firefox on the Linux side somehow share stored form fields with the Windows side?

I noticed Amazon.com had remembered some stuff I added to my cart on the Windows side. Maybe it's session cookies?

Comment: Chrome has a syncing feature that syncs over login information, maybe Firefox has the same functionality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are are looking at ***Firefox Sync*** as the most likely culprit:

[image: Firefox Sync]